# Is it possible to route DPs to HDMI from the HD3SS215 without using vias?

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I'm working with the [HD3SS215](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hd3ss215.pdf) and have found that while the datasheet does have a typical application for HDMI (9.2.2, p19), it is difficult to route to that connector from the IC; the pinout from the IC (D0, D1, D2, D3) doesn't match HDMI pinout sequence (D2, D1, D0, D3).

As with all HDMI applications, the datasheet has the expected "avoid the use of vias" line, but since the lines need to cross over each other to connect the HD3SS215 to HDMI, I can't see any way other than using vias.

[image: HDMI with HD3SS215]

*Note:* I haven't finished tuning the DP lengths yet (D3 is about 10mm longer).

Comment: Just a thought: this is a passive switch, right? so, even if you "swap" the polarity of a differential HDMI line in, as long as you do the same swap on the output, you'd still have a valid signal. If you don't need pin swapping between HDMI connector and chip, you can route all your bottom traces on the top in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Oh, that's a thought!

Comment: @MarcusMüller new to differential pair routing here. By swap the polarity do you mean route like D0 to D2 and D2 to D0, which you're saying is fine because this is the input to a switch and so you can do the same swap on the output from the switch?

Comment: @InBedded16 I think that might be implied; you can use whatever pin on the switch you like, as long as the source and sink match at either end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Use a DisplayPort connector**

The line sequence on the HD3SS215 (D0, D1, D2, D3) matches the DisplayPort connector, which I suspect this IC was actually designed for. I would guess HDMI is there for compatibility.

Here's what the PCB layout of the HD3SS215 looks like when used with a DisplayPort connector.

[image: HD3SS215 with DP]

Source: [DPSwitch](https://github.com/jorticus/DPSwitch) by Jared Sanson.

**Option 2: Don't match the pins**

Credit to Marcus Müller (in the comments).

The HD3SS215 is a passive switch, so for HDMI, perhaps we don't need to match the pins up to P/N or even D*n*.

[image: Schematic]

Which gives us a much neater PCB layout.

[image: HD3SS215 to HDMI]

Answer (score 2):

You can have vias in high-speed lines, you just need to consider the return paths and via stubs. I'm going to assume you have a proper ground plane on the next layer down, as close as possible to your signal layer. If your board technology allows for backdrilling or blind vias/uvias, then use those. If you have to use thru vias, you might be ok if you provide adjacent thru vias connected to ground with decoupling to the power plane.

As with any high-speed design, a lot of the effort is put into the board stackup to ensure good signal integrity. With a bad stackup, the length matching/via avoidance is moot.

Comment: Yep, ground plane next layer down.